# Define two attributes in html button and passing to jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html

here is my a class Button in html, inside you can find the id with one value group_name. But I need to pass another variable `$group_search_overview->groupsid` to jquery.

```
@foreach($groups_search_overview as $group_search_overview)
            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-block test_uebergabe" id="{{$group_search_overview->group_name}}">                   
                {{$group_search_overview->group_name}}
            </a>
@endforeach
```

This is my jquery script

```
$(document).on('click', '.test_uebergabe', function () {
                var idgroups = $(this).attr("id");
                $('.modal-body').html(idgroups);
                $('#dataModal').modal({show: true});  
});
```

How can I send a second variable to jquery? What's the correct way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: To save custom data to html element you can use the [`data`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) attribute, to access these with jQuery use [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/)

Answer (score 0):

Just add a data attribute:

```
<a data-group="{{your variable here}} class="btn btn-primary btn-block test_uebergabe" id="{{$group_search_overview->group_name}}"">
```

Than in jquery:

```
let group = $(this).data('group');
```

where `this` would be the currently focussed button.